# How to upload objects to local s3 using pre-signed url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Writing test cases to test file upload functionality using presigned url. I am running localstack in docker local as aws environment. I am able to test direct upload to local stack, however when I try to upload using presigned url it is failing as my presigned url is generated with https and my local stack is running on http.

Any suggestions on how to test in local?

Comment: I have the same issue -- After adding the host that localstack returns to my hosts file so it can be resolved, I try and perform the PUT file to the URL, but Localstack returns HTTP 400 and reports "InvalidBucketName"

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is not possible since the hostname and domain name in the pre-signed URL (.s3..amazonaws.com) would always be resolved to the remote/cloud AWS and not localhost, irrespective of the protocol.